# After a while firebase insertion from my android app stops inserting

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys I am really puzzled at this, I developed an android app with my BaaS being firebase n everything has been working fine until today.

I tried postin/inserting a record to my firebase dbase on the app but its not inserting -nothing is changing.

I didnt change any of my code n i only got into my app today after a few weeks ago wen i completed it.

Can someone assist me with how to resolve this or wer the problem could be.

I would appreciate it.

Comment: Well there's not much to go on without any code samples...but if it was working before and absolutely no code was changed then it's possible the firebase service was temporarily interrupted on their end - you can check their status here: http://status.firebase.com/ ... this has happened to me on rare occasions but it has always been restored in a few minutes so it would be worth checking again later today to ensure the issue is on your end.

Comment: Thanks i think i so wer the problem was my session limit had expired

Comment: So it was logging in automatically with an expired session

Comment: So it's all good now?

Comment: S it is just a question why doesnt firebase have a message to say session expired

Comment: Yes its working sorry i hv been offline